# Ec2 Proxy Between one Ec2 instance and An API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy

I have an ec2 instance that hosts a webserver. Requests to an external API are currently made from here. I'm just wondering if its possible / how you would go about making these requests to a proxy / server of some sort and then redirecting those requests to the API? I've set up another instance that currently has squid on it, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go about this. Below is how I imagine the flow to go, I just can't find any examples of this being done, so its making me think that I might be looking in the wrong place.

Webserver(ec2) -> proxy(?) -> External API

Any help / suggestions would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, you could just put your EC2 instance in a public subnet. Add a Security Group to only open the required Inbound ports (eg 80, 443) and leave the Outbound rules to the default "Allow All".

Your EC2 instance can then access the Internet and the external API without needing a proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The main reasoning behind the proxy is to have a static IP. Every time the ec2 webserver IP changes, I must inform the guys providing the api, and they have to re whitelist me. I thought a proxy would solve that?

Comment: Do public subnets have static IPs?

Comment: If you need a static IP for your EC2 instance, take a look at Elastic IP addresses:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Comment: You can allocate Elastic IP addresses and attach them to EC2 instances. EIPs do not change.

Comment: You can create an [Elastic IP addresses - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) (which is a static IP address), then associated the Elastic IP address with your instance. You should create a Domain Name and link it to the Elastic IP address by using a `CNAME` record.

Comment: OK great thanks! Just out of curiosity, how would you go about doing this (forwarding ec2 requests) through a proxy server (if its possible)?